Can't install opencv-python on Rasberry PI 2
I am trying to install opencv-python on my on Rasberry PI 2 but I always run in this error.
I thought it was because it is not possible to install OpenCV using pip on Python3.9, so I have downgrade to Python3.6 but the error is still the same.
I also tried upgrading my set-up tool wheel with pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel but nothing changed.
Do you have an idea what can possibly be?
pi@raspberrypi:~/dataAquisition $ pip3 install opencv-python
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
Collecting opencv-python
  Using cached opencv-python-4.10.0.84.tar.gz (95.1 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Collecting numpy>=1.17.0 (from opencv-python)
  Using cached https://www.piwheels.org/simple/numpy/numpy-2.0.0-cp39-cp39-linux_armv7l.whl (5.8 MB)
Building wheels for collected packages: opencv-python
  Building wheel for opencv-python (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Building wheel for opencv-python (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [11 lines of output]
      patching file opencv/3rdparty/openexr/IlmImf/ImfSystemSpecific.cpp
      /tmp/pip-build-env-qbrhbnub/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cmake/data/bin/cmake: error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-qbrhbnub/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/skbuild/setuptools_wrap.py", line 643, in setup
          cmkr = cmaker.CMaker(cmake_executable)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-qbrhbnub/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/skbuild/cmaker.py", line 145, in __init__
          self.cmake_version = get_cmake_version(self.cmake_executable)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-qbrhbnub/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/skbuild/cmaker.py", line 102, in get_cmake_version
          raise SKBuildError(msg) from err
      
      Problem with the CMake installation, aborting build. CMake executable is /tmp/pip-build-env-qbrhbnub/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cmake/data/bin/cmake
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for opencv-python
**Failed to build opencv-python**
**ERROR: ERROR: Failed to build installable wheels for some pyproject.toml based projects (opencv-python)**

I thought it was because it is not possible to install OpenCV using pip on Python3.9, so I have downgrade to Python3.6 but the error is still the same.

it could be useful to know: 1) which OS and version 2) pip version 3) cmake version

is the issue concerning only opencv or also other packages? have you tried to install first numpy?

CMake is complaining about missing libssl.so.3 -- did you verify it exists, and if not, did you attempt to rectify that problem?

RPi2 is just 32-bit ARM. opencv-python has binary packages for aarch64 but not for 32-bit ARM. OP has no choice but to go through the build process.
